# php strtotime gives strange result

Tags: php, strtotime

Can someone explain why

```
echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime("Wednesday, 1 January, 2014"));
```

returns

```
2013-01-02
```

Comment: "Wednesday, January 1, 2014" will return the right date

Comment: `strtotime()` is not magic, it tried to figure out which of [these formats](http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) the string is, and yours is not one of those. GIGO

Comment: It isn't able to determine the year so it is defaulting to the current one.

Comment: What actually happens here: `"1 January, 2014"` is invalid (comma is only valid after `m dd` not `dd m`), so it ignores the 2014 and interprets as "the first Wednesday after 1 January of this year".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the comma after January:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime("Wednesday, 1 January 2014"));
```

`strtotime()` while flexible, still has strict standards of formatting.

Comment: I thought at first that it was a good solution, but it doesn't work for all dates: `echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("Wednesday, 13 February 2014"));` returns `2014-02-19`

Comment: @MathieuImbert hopefully my comment on the question explains that one: it's the first Wednesday after 2014-02-13.

Comment: the `13th of Feb` is on a thursday. It's picking the following wednesday which is the `19th`(your result).

Answer (score 0):

Give proper format

```
strtotime("Wednesday, January 1, 2014")
```